# Safari/Chrome Not Posting Values When Changed Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, google-chrome, safari, onsubmit

I have a few hidden form elements like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numberOfAdults" />
```

I then have an onsubmit function that does some addition and puts the sum into the hidden fields:

```
form.numberOfAdults.value = numAdults;
```

The form is submitted depending on if this function returns true or false. When the form is submitted, IE7+ and Firefox show the changed value from the onsubmit function. Safari and Chrome do not. However, if I give the hidden inputs default values:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="numberOfAdults" value="2" />
```

Then the value gets passed. Why are Safari and Chrome ignoring these changed values?

**EDIT: Here is the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/2q8SX/**

Comment: Could you post your function?

Comment: Is this function registered via eventlistener? or onclick attribute? form and function code would be nice

Comment: Need to see code of **isset**

Comment: @kirilloid Code for isset added.

Comment: I'm really confused. Could you add form html as well?
You may paste it into http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @kirilloid Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/2q8SX/ Problem arises when you select more than one room w/ different number of adults/children in each room. After submitting, an alert will tell you how many adults/children you have. That value will carry over in IE/Firefox, but not Chrome/Safari.

Comment: This code works ok for me in Google Chrome 4.1.249.1045 (42898) and Safari 4.0.4 (531.21.10), WinXP. Yes, for several rooms too. I've found some bugs in your code, though: <script lang_a_ge.. and <script lang_aua_ge...                 Just add value="0" to inputs after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a wild guess:

give your submit button:

```
onclick="yourFunction(); return false;"
```

and add to your function() as it's last command:

```
document.getElementByTagName('form').submit();
```